# How to parse jqwidgets (jqx) date with format?

Tags: javascript, date, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

Basically I have date format which comes from server and which will be not known before and a date that was already formatted in this format, e.g. the format is "dd/MM/yyyy" and the date is "21/01/2018" (two strings). The format that uses jqx differs from the default JS one, as I can see.

What I need to do is to parse it to JavaScript date object. I couldn't find the answer in the official documentation.

Is there any easy was of parsing the date string if you know the date format, using JS, jqwidgets or momentjs?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I've finished with inner jqx method that does that exact thing:

```
var parsedDate = $.jqx.dataFormat.parsedate(src, format);
```

Where format in this case is "dd/MM/yyyy" and src is "21/01/2018".

P.S. Thanks for the guy that posted anwer with the code that used $.jqx.dataFormat, that really helped me to find `parsedate` method.